# Google Chrome extension to remember filepath of last uploaded file

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can remember the filepath of the last uploaded file on a website's form (e.g. that uses [`input type="file"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14889239/395857)). Bonus point if it can remember the filepath on a per-website basis.

---

My use case:

I upload many images to StackExchange as I find they make questions and answers much clearer. I often upload temporary images that I simply name "C:\Untitled.png". Though I already have a [voice command](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227017/178179) to take care of that, it would be great if there were a Google Chrome extension that would remember the filepath of the last uploaded image so that one doesn't need to specify the filepath again when the new image to upload has the same filepath.

This way, instead of having:

[image]

The `choose file` field would already have the previous filepath, which would be convenient when I don't need to change it:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is even possible since you can't [re-pouplate file inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842571/can-you-re-populate-file-inputs-after-failed-form-submission-with-php-or-javascr) with JavaScript.