# Tool to remember last uploaded file (Windows)?

Tags: windows

I am looking for something that tells Windows Explorer to remember what was the last picture or file I uploaded, so that when I go to upload a picture again, it instantly takes me to that last used picture/photo/file (which ever it is).

Comment: Which version of windows are you on?  Windows tends to do this by default (from the same application anyway).  I don't know that this is a tool recommendation so much as why isn't windows doing this.

Comment: Pretty similar: [Google Chrome extension to remember filepath of last uploaded file](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7320/903), maybe dup I let you see.

Comment: I definitely don't want that. Doesn't it already do that? I am kinda having trouble thinking about how to phrase my question but I do know what I want.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z0FK.jpg < I kinda want it to be like this when I click on upload again.

Comment: You want openfiledialog box to remember the last selected location?

Comment: @Cheruvian- I want the openfiledialog to automatically highlight or jump the last select file.